# changing value of cells in a range without looping

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Hi is possible to change the cells that contain specific value to another without the use of looping or extra code (is there any built in function in Excel)?

for example in Excel 2007 I have a range (A1:B3)

```
       A    B    C
  1   -1    56   100
  2   100   45   1
  3   34   -999  0
```

now I want to change the cells' value to 7 if it contains 100, so now our range becomes

```
       A    B    C
  1   -1    56   7
  2    7    45   1
  3   34   -999  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit for Excel 2007:

Home->Editing->Find & Select->Replace. Also see the IF function, you could create a copy on another sheet using something like

```
=IF(A1= 7,100, A1)
```

and drag the right-hand corner to create a copy of all the cells (it will automatically change the formula to use B1, etc)